# Phantomjs rendering not correct on Heroku

Tags: pdf, heroku, phantomjs

I'm deploying Node.js app to Heroku and one part of that app is to create HTML report and optionally offer PDF download. For this I'm using phantomjs to do html->pdf convertion but phantom doesn't render it properly. HTML pages are identical local and on heroku but rendered PDFs are not.

Comparison:
[image]

Is there some special configuration for phantomjs I neeed to do to run properly on Heroku?

Comment: Different how? If I see it correctly, there is a difference in the font. Installing more fonts might fix the issue.

Comment: I tried with Roboto (also used in screenshot) and with Arial and it didn't make a difference. What other font do you suggest?